# SUM values or take MAX to SUM depending on value

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sum, max

I have a query to select some shippingcost and I want to sum them up in a special way.

Sample Data:

```
supplierID | articleID | sumUP | shippingCost
10         | 100       | 1     | 20
10         | 101       | 1     | 15
20         | 200       | 0     | 15
20         | 201       | 0     | 10
30         | 300       | 0     | 10
=============================================
Sum should be:                   60
```

What I want to achive is to sum up all `shippingCost` values, but since `sumUP` on `supplierID 20` and `30` is `0`, i just want to have the maximum value of these suppliers.

so

> supplier 10 should have 35 (sum of values)
>
> supplier 20 should have 15 (maximum value)
>
> supplier 30 should have 10 (maximum value)

in sum it should be 60.

I tried a lot of complex querys but always got stuck when I want to decide to sum or take max and sum all afterwards.

Is this even possible with a mysql statement? (of course subquerys in it).

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: Are you looking for `... GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` ?

Comment: and how can i decide between max and sum when grouping?

Comment: You can use CASE.

Comment: *"and how can i decide between max and sum when grouping? "* Seams/feels like then i have misinterpreted your sample data and expected result then as `Sum should be:                   60` made it look like you where searching for `WITH ROLLUP` ... See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Is there a case the same supplier can have 1 row with sumup = 0 and another with sumup = 1?

Comment: @forpas no, the value comes from an supplier table and is boolean, its just there to see what value were in the supplier table.

Comment: @RaymondNijland sorry when my post is not 100% clear... I tried to explain it as easy as possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `case` expression to either return the `SUM()` or the `MAX()`:

```
select supplierID,
       case when max(sumUP) = 1 then sum(shippingCost) else max(shippingCost) end
from tablename
group by supplierID
```

## EDIT BY Dwza

As forpas mentioned, this statement just gives me the result that needs to be summed up. The total statement could look like:

```
select sum(my.result) from
    (select supplierID,
        case when max(sumUP) = 1 then sum(shippingCost) else max(shippingCost) end as result
from tablename
group by supplierID) as my
```

Comment: this looks quite suitable... i will test this one and return with a comment or accapting the answere :D

Comment: but I think it pushes me in the right direction, and SOF is not here to write my code so this forces me to think in an other direction and than come back with feedback :)

Comment: in the end this was the right solution, thank you... in my case I had to do some more improvements, but like I sayed, if this solves my problem, ill return and accept :)

Answer (score 2):

First `group by supplierid` to get the sum and the max of `shippingcost` for each supplier and then use conditional aggregation on the results:

```
select
  sum((t.sumup = 0) * maxshippingcost + (t.sumup = 1) * sumshippingcost) total
from (  
  select supplierid,
    max(sumup) sumup,
    max(shippingcost) maxshippingcost,
    sum(shippingcost) sumshippingcost
  from tablename
  group by supplierid
) t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ef4REEocYFWQ7o38pi31L5/1).
Or with a CASE expression:

```
select
  sum(
    case t.sumup 
      when 0 then maxshippingcost
      when 1 then sumshippingcost
    end  
  ) total
from (  
  select supplierid,
    max(sumup) sumup,
    max(shippingcost) maxshippingcost,
    sum(shippingcost) sumshippingcost
  from tablename
  group by supplierid
) t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ef4REEocYFWQ7o38pi31L5/2).

Comment: Good sample... in the end similar to the other ones but very suitable to my problem because I had to use multiple subselects or better "nested" subselects

Comment: @Dwza the answer that you accepted does not return the expected result.

Comment: Actually it does, he only forgot to sum everything up in the end. But for me this just was a sample and I just needed the info to use case. Never saw or used it before so this is the correct answere for me. And all other answeres who have the right result, got a vote up from me. Same as yours. :) but, i will fix this in the answere.

Answer (score 1):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(supplier_ID INT NOT NULL 
,articleID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
,sum_UP INT NOT NULL
,shippingCost INT NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(10,100,1,20),
(10,101,1,15),
(20,200,0,15),
(20,201,0,10),
(30,300,0,10);

SELECT SUM(x) total
  FROM 
     ( SELECT supplier_id, MAX(shippingcost) x FROM my_table WHERE sum_up = 0 GROUP BY supplier_id
       UNION
       SELECT supplier_id, shippingcost FROM my_table WHERE sum_up = 1
     ) a;

+-------+
| total |
+-------+
|    60 |
+-------+
```

Comment: i tried this as well, but this may cause some problem because this query could be called several times in the same second... and dropping the table when someone else is currently on it will lead into data loose ^^  this would work it the name of the table could be a hash or session ID. And i used `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_table (SELECT * FROM XY)` so i dont need to declair the column types.

Answer (score 1):

I use `case` and `group by`

```sql
select supplier_id,
       case
           when sum_up = 0
               then max(shipping_cost)
           when sum_up = 1
               then sum(shipping_cost) end as total
from table_name
group by supplier_id, sum_up;
```

The result as follows:

```
supplier_id, sum_up
20           15
10           35
30           10
```

Now, I can sum it

```
select sum(total)
from (
         select supplier_id,
                case
                    when sum_up = 0
                        then max(shipping_cost)
                    when sum_up = 1
                        then sum(shipping_cost) end as total
         from cd.sample
         group by supplier_id, sum_up
) a;
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. In my case I had to wrap everything into nested subselects. But than you as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
      SELECT sum(A.SumShipping) as TotalSum 
    FROM (SELECT supplierID, if(sumup = 1, sum(shippingcost), max(shippingcost)) 
as SumShipping FROM tablename group by supplierID)  as A;
```

Comment: This answere also helped me and solves the problem as well... in my case with a few changes :)